Repurposing of Office commands not working
I'm trying to repurpose a built-in command using the following XML, but it doesn't appear to be call the onAction callback function:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <commands>
    <command idMso="Undo" onAction="UndoButton_Click" /> <!--doesn't work-->
  </commands>
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="MyCustomTab" label="Custom">
        ...

Code-behind looks like this:
public void UndoButton_Click(IRibbonControl control)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Custom Undo");
}

Incidentally, the same custom ribbon fires button callbacks just fine. It is just the command callbacks that do not appear to work.
Reproduction is very simple. Just create a new Excel VSTO add-in in Visual Studio, add a custom Ribbon (XML, not Visual Designer) and replace the corresponding portion in the default ribbon template with the code above. Then add the above handler in code behind and run).
